# Server is taking more time than client using TCP

Tags: tcp

I am working on client server architecture. I am sending around 8000000 bytes data from the client to the server. I am a bit surprised to know, that my client can send data in just 704 ms, but whу server is required 3922 ms to receive this data.

Though I am not doing any operation on my data on the server-side but just simply receive it. client and server  hardware architecture  also same. I checked Data flow using WIRESHARK but there it dosent seems to be `~6 times` difference between client and server time ?

- What are the general assumptions on why do the server is always takes more time than the client ?
- How overhead(TCP, UDP, Ethernet header) affect the communication.

Note: I am using `std::Clock()`to measure my execution time of both client and server, using Ethernet connection to transfer data to server.

Statistics:

- 8000000 bytes(client704 ms, server 3922ms)
- 80000000 bytes(client7175 ms, server 13188ms)
- 800000000 bytes(client72797 ms, server 77719ms)
- 8000000000 bytes(client72797 ms, server 77719ms)

//Client Code

```
    std::clock_t c_start = std::clock();
    for( int i = 0; i <100000; i++)// writing data to buffer
    {    
        m_vector.push_back(i);
    }
    uint32_t siz = (m_vector.size())*sizeof(double);
    int total_bytes = 0;
    int count=0;
    for(int j=0; j<1000; j++)
    {  
        bytesSent = send(ConnectSocket,(char*)&siz, 4, 0);
        assert (bytesSent == sizeof (uint32_t));
        std::cout<<"length information is in:"<<bytesSent<<"bytes"<<std::endl;
        bytesSent = send(ConnectSocket,(char*)m_vector.data(), siz, 0);
        total_bytes = total_bytes+bytesSent;
    }
      closesocket (ConnectSocket);
    std::clock_t c_end = std::clock();
    std::cout << "CPU time used: "<< 1000.0 * (c_end-c_start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC<< " ms\n";
    WSACleanup();
   system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

// Server code

```
while(1)
    {
        //code to received data length from the client
        int length_received = recv(m_socket,(char*)&nlength, 4, 0); 
        m_vector.resize(nlength/sizeof(double));

        //code to received data length from the client
        bytesRecv = recv(m_socket,(char*)m_vector.data(), nlength, 0);
        count++;
            if((count==1))
            {
            std::clock_t c_start = std::clock();
            }

        //1st time data
        if((bytesRecv > 0 ))
        {
            total_br = total_br + bytesRecv;
            v1=m_vector;
            cout<<"Server: Received bytes are"<<total_br<<std::endl;
        }else {break;}

        }
                closesocket (m_socket);
        std::clock_t c_end = std::clock();
        std::cout << "CPU time used: "<< 1000.0 * (c_end-c_start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC<< " ms\n";
        WSACleanup();
       system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: You're probably measuring the wrong thing.  Show us your code.

Comment: In particular, you're probably measuring the time it takes to write to a buffer.

Comment: @SLaks I think code might be not required can you please have a look on statistics i just added. Sorry for previous version i corrected some facts. Why i am seeing such differnces i.e less time difference when data size grows ?

Comment: Your stats don't tell us what you're actually measuring, and that was Slak's point.

Comment: @SLaks Here is the code.

Comment: You're including the resizing of `m_vector` in your timings, which could potentially be a long delay.

Comment: You have lots of bugs in your code. In particular, you don't handle the case where `length_received` is more than zero but less than four.

Answer (score 0):

1. Sending in TCP just means writing the data into the local socket send buffer. The actual putting of TCP segments onto the network is asynchronous. That means that even after you've closed the socket, not all the data has actually been transferred. So making sender-side time measurements is basically meaningless.
2. There's nothing remarkable about taking 3922ms to receive a transfer of that size.